# Cannot clear browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I am having an issue on my MAC. I have created a site at easy.auction and have uploaded a logo and favicon however regardless of what I try and what browser I use I cannot see the updated version.

I have tried a CMD + R, I have cleared all website history, cookies and browsing history in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, I have restarted Chrome and my Mac. I have opened DEV tools and right clicked on the reload button and selected 'Empty Cache and Reload'. I have tried on 2 phones (iPhone and Android) all to no avail.

Easy Auction are advising that they can see the changes their end. If I use a service like [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/ie/11/http%3A%2F%2Fauction.outyego.com%2F) then I can see the changes but just cannot get the changes to show on my devices.

I'm really stuck as to what I can do, does anyone have any other suggestions? The URL in question is auction.outyego.com. I have also been into net-internals and cleared the event cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel stupid now - The site uses cloudflare and it seems that I had to manually purge the cache to view it on my devices. This does seem odd however as I did try multiple devices and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In **chrome** Press **Command+Option+I**, go to **Network tab**, Check the **"Disable cache option"**

while any of the dev panel is open you can reload you page without cache now

[image: what to check for no cache]